Wiring a new fan motor to my home air conditioner
My original house A/C fan (condenser) motor stopped working. It was an F48SJ6MA6. They're no longer made. I purchased an OCB1026A. They come with different combinations of wires.
The original motor had green (ground), white (neutral), brown (starter cap), black (high speed) and red (low speed). The red wire was not used. The white and brown wires went to the starter cap, the white connected on a common bus with the incoming neutral line from the power source.
My problem is that I can't get the new motor working. The schematic is duplicated below. It appears to me that the new motor's yellow wire substitutes for the old motor's white wire. Black and red appear to be the same compared to the old motor. Brown, too. What I don't understand is the orange and purple wires. I'm unfamiliar with the little triangle they're connecting to. I'm guessing it's chassis ground, but before I hook it up, I wanted some confirmation.
Also, the notes state to use the "brown and orange" wires for counter-clockwise rotation, the others for clockwise, so I'm planning to leave the orange wire unconnected... but I don't get the brown not being used. I should think the starter cap is required.
Is it correct to connect the purple wire (which has a fusable link. No other wire does) to the same screw as the ground?
If this question is better suited for DIY.StackExchange, I have no objection to its migration.


OK! I figured it out. That triangle symbol must mean "join these two together" because when I did that with the orange and purple wires the fan turned on and works fine. I believe I misinterpreted the comment about switching rotation as it must be that putting orange on the start capacitor and connecting brown with purple reverses the rotation. However, I haven't tried this.
Hopefully this helps out someone in the future trying to replace an old A/C fan motor with a modern equivalent.

The triangle symbol here is a stylized representation of a wire nut. It is not very helpful unless you know enough to know what it could stand for. It’s not used in any standardized way here, just an arbitrary depiction.
